# Is there a Python function that throws away or ignores negative values?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This program is supposed to find where a string starts (at "ATG") and slice up until an end point (at "TAG", "TAA", or "TGA"). Whenever I try to calculate the lastIndex using the function I created and the provided test string, I continuously received -1 as the index. Is there a Python function that throws away or ignores negative values?

```
genome = 'TTATGTTTTAAGGATGGGGCGTTAGTT'
newGenome = ''

def firstIndex(genome):
    return genome.find("ATG")

def lastIndex(genome):
    return min(genome.find("TAG"), genome.find("TAA"), genome.find("TGA"))


for i in range(genome.count("ATG")):
    newgenome = genome[firstIndex(genome):lastIndex(genome)]
```

Comment: I suspect a regular expression will before rather well, e.g. `for s in re.finditer('ATG.*?(?:TAG|TAA|TGA)', genome): print s.group(0)` would print `ATGTTTTAA` and `ATGGGGCGTTAG`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find` returns -1 if it doesn't find anything.  So your `lastIndex` function will always return -1 if *any* of the codons aren't found.

You don't really want to "ignore -1", you want to find the first instance of `TAG|TAA|TGA`.  (fortunately you provided your code so we dodged the worst part of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))

Your code also suffers from being inefficient - it has to make 3 whole passes through the entire string just to find the first occurance of one of three codons.  We can improve that by using regex.

Try using `re.finditer` so you only have to make one pass through your genome:

```
next(m.start() for m in re.finditer('TAG|TAA|TGA',genome))
Out[9]: 8
```

Using `next` is nice since we can provide a default value if nothing is yielded from the generator expression:

```
def lastIndex(genome):
    return next((m.start() for m in re.finditer('TAG|TAA|TGA',genome)),None)
```

Comment: By using an iterator, the `lastIndex` function only makes a single pass - but the whole program still makes two passes. You could avoid one pass by exploiting the fact that `ATG` and `TAG|TAA|TGA` alternative, i.e. the former only needs to search from either the start of the string or the last occurrance of `TAG|TAA|TGA`, and the former only needs to start searching from the last occurrence from `ATG`.

Comment: you are correct - I didn't try to bleeding-edge optimize the entirety of the OP's program.  It's likely that strictly-one-pass is not faster in real life situations because the start codon is often near the start of the string so that `find` is more-or-less constant time.

Comment: Though, on reflection it looks like all the OP is trying to do is extract stuff between start and stop codons - he doesn't really care about the indices.  So yes replacing his entire code with a regex might be reasonable since it is just simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if a function that ignores a negative value would suffice here, since you would have to change your `for` loop accordingly. One way to achieve the result would be to modify your code as:

```
def lastIndex(genome):
    val = min(genome.find("TAG"), genome.find("TAA"), genome.find("TGA"))
    return val if val > -1 else None


for i in range(genome.count("ATG")):
    li = lastIndex(genome)
    if li:
        newgenome = genome[firstIndex(genome):li]
    else:
         newgenome = genome[firstIndex(genome):]
```

EDIT: My answer was directed towards providing a way to ignore the negative return value from your `lastIndex` method and handling it accordingly in the subsequent `for` loop irrespective of the logic of how you the return value is actually calculated. However, as @roippi points out, there is a flaw in the way you calculate the return value for `lastIndex` and his answer addresses that.

Comment: this is wrong.  In a string containing `TAG` but not `TAA` or `TGA`, `lastIndex` will *still* return `None` because the `min` of those three `find` operations will be -1.

Comment: In which case the OP's original code is wrong too? I just reorganized his code to fit what he expects from a return value. My suggestion does not change the original intended logic.

Comment: May be his question is not directed clearly then. My answer correctly answers his question of " Is there a Python function that throws away or ignores negative values?"